# Retrieve polling URL each time a request is sent - Socket.io

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I am currently looking to see if I can pick up the URL which is used in polling via socket.io E.G

http://127.0.0.1:8000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MSTH-j0&sid=bycdflRlaXRivG9MAACx

The reason for this is am going to do an override with that URL. Is there anything in socket that would return me this value each time I send through a request via polling.

Can I return this value somehow as is or am I going to have to construct it manually via

```
socket.on('ping', function () {
    console.log('ping');
    console.log(socket);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer - I was able to get the url I was polling via:

```
socket.on('ping', function () {
    console.log('ping');
    console.log(socket.io.engine.transport.pollXhr.uri);
});
```